# F5 LTM config through tmsh - At least one monitor

Tags: f5, big-ip, tmsh

f5-LTM version 11.6

Hi,
I'm looking for the syntax to create a pool via tmsh 
with 2 monitors (monitor_A, monitor_B)
with 'Availability Requirement' set to 'At Least...' '1' Health Monitor(s)

checked https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/bigip-tmsh-reference-11-6-0.html 
to no avail.
It only shows the following syntax:
 create pool ... monitor [name]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

`tmsh create ltm pool mypool \
monitor min 1 of {http https} \
members add { 192.168.103.10:80 192.168.103.11:80}`